# Setting allocationSize for @GenericGenerator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I had previous code for a `@SequenceGenerator` with parameter `allocationSize=1`

I needed to override the `SequenceGenerator` with a custom `@GenericGenerator`. However I don't see a way to specify my `allocationSize` parameter inside my custom `GenericGenerator` strategy class. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer for this, yes it is possible my creating a CustomGenerator and then using @GenericGenerator and in that CustomGenerator use the code like below:

```
public class UseExistingOrGenerateIdGenerator extends SequenceHiLoGenerator {
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
        return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) throws MappingException {

        params.put(org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.SEQUENCE, "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE");

        params.put(SequenceHiLoGenerator.MAX_LO, String.valueOf("49"));
        super.configure(type, params, dialect);
    }

}
```